# Благодарность сообществу SO

Tags: обсуждение, вопросы

### Предупреждаю сразу, что это не вопрос и не предложение :)

Честно говоря я не нашел такого раздела на сайте как книга отзывов и пожеланий. Это скорее не вопрос, а просто пост о том за что я благодарен этому сообществу и его пользователям. Поэтому если этот пост-вопрос будет удален я не обижусь.

Зарегистрировался на SO я давно, но вопросы я начал задавать сравнительно недавно. Начинал я с совсем с тупых вопросов, и задавал их огромное количество. По факту я не читал даже перед тем как задавать вопрос (наверное большинство новичков так поступает). Мне много народу помогало, еще больше закидывало помидорами за мои тупые вопросы. Я очень долго трясся над своим рейтингом и было очень обидно когда набранные таким непосильным трудом балы могли быть с легкостью потеряны из-за обычного человеческого мнения.

Постепенно я начинал понимать тех людей которые мне говорили, что нужно сразу искать и пытаться самостоятельно решить свою проблему, а потом уже вываливать все сюда. Через некоторое время я начал предварительно искать на SO и enSO похожие проблемы, потом искал в интернете и если уже совсем было все плохо то шёл сюда за помощью. Я начал самостоятельно учить и искать по интересующей меня теме. **Я начал учится искать и находить.** Это был очень долгий путь.

Спустя некоторое время у меня стали появляться вопросы, на которые я через некоторое время давал ответ, найдя его на просторах интернета. И вот совсем недавно я опубликовал свой первый самоответ - ответ на вопрос который создавал специально чтобы поделится своими наработками.

Я очень благодарен этому сообществу. Я благодарен пользователям: @woesss, @McDaggen, @Suvitruf, @Barmaley и многим другим людям которые относились ко мне как к новичку и разжовывали все непонятные вопросы. Список этих пользователей очень большой и я прошу прощения у тех, кого я не упомянул здесь. Я вам всем очень благодарен за ваше понимание и снисхождение.

Я думаю что создатели ruSO и enSO преследовали цель создания большой базы знаний, но у них получилось нечто большее чем просто куча полезной информации. Это сообщество собрало огромную аудиторию состоящую из людей которые занимаются своим любимым делом и не против поделится своими знаниями с другими. Здесь можно найти единомышленников которые всегда придут на помощь, не глядя на твои политические, религиозные и другие предпочтения. Люди со всего мира общаются и делятся информацией.

### **Я очень благодарен SO :) СПАСИБО**

P.S. Дорогие модераторы и все те кто будет проверять мой вопрос, я не обижусь если мой вопрос будет удален или отредактирован должным образом. Заголовок я думаю можно как-то переформулировать по-другому. Метки я думаю что тоже нужно пересмотреть. Спасибо за ваши труды)

Comment: Если хочется больше участвовать в жизни ruSO, загляните еще и в чат: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22462

Comment: знаете я вообще могу конечно общаться в чате, но я иногда опасаюсь реакции людей на мои сообщения. тем не менее эта сторона ruSO еще не совсем изведана мной)

Comment: Да мы вроде не кусаемся. Может у вас синдром самозванца? Такое не редкость в ИТ. Можно для начала просто почитать чат в рид-онли (из приватной вкладки) - а когда будет что сказать/спросить - можно и залогиниться.

Comment: честно говоря первый раз слышу про синдром самозванца, с названия понятно, что это что-то не очень хорошее)) но не могли бы вы поподробнее объяснить что имели в виду?

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko это когда человек считает, что не заслуживает достигнутого успеха, предполагая, что окружающие ошибочно думают иначе. В общем, если в двух словах, низкая самооценка.

Comment: @Suvitruf, ну с самооценкой у меня возможно и есть проблемы конечно, но за свои успехи я вроде спокоен)) в любом случае буду постепенно выползать в чат, там можно пообщаться с такими же как и я разработчиками)

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko не бойтесь, мы не кусаемся. В чате довольно доброжелательная атмосфера (:

Comment: @Suvitruf, спасибо, буду ознакамливатся с тематикой текущего разговора и тоже буду что-то писать)